# Equations of motion for the Yang-Mills $SU(2)$ theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills

I have an exercise for Yang-Mills theory. I can't find answer anywhere.

> *Derive equations of motion for the Yang-Mills theory with the gauge group $SU(2)$ interacting with $SU(2)$ doublet of scalar fields.*

I don't even know how to derive EOM for Lagrangian here. Any help? Or any source for appropriate handbook? (I've been using Maggiore, it doesn't have EOM for Yang-Mills here.)

Comment: I have two questions - 1. Do you know of the Euler-Lagrange equations and how they are derived? 2. Do you know the Lagrangian of Yang-Mills theory coupled to scalars/fermions, etc?

Comment: 1. Yup, i know basis for classical field theory. 2. Nope.

Answer (score 6):

The Lagrangian of Yang-Mills theory coupled to scalars/fermions, etc. takes the form
$$
{\cal L}_{YM} = - \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} + (D_\mu \phi) (D^\mu \phi)^* + i {\bar \psi} \gamma^\mu D_\mu \psi + \cdots
$$
where the $\cdots$ represents other interactions terms that might be present. Let me explain the notation in the above expression.

1. $\phi_i$ and $\psi_i$ are multiplets in some representation $R$ of the gauge group $G$. Here, $i = 1, \cdots, \dim R$
2. The generators in representation $R$ are denoted as $T^a$. These are normalized to satisfy
   $$
   [T^a, T^b] = i f^{ab}{}_c T^c,~~~~ \text{Tr} ( T^a T^b )= \frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}
   $$
   In other words, the $T_{ij}^a$'s are just some set of matrices satisfying the above properties.
3. The covariant derivatives acting on the fields is
   \begin{align}
   (D_\mu \phi)_i &= \partial_\mu \phi_i - i g T^a_{ij} A_\mu^a \phi_j \\
   (D_\mu \psi)_i &= \partial_\mu \psi_i - i g T^a_{ij} A_\mu^a \psi_j \\
   \end{align}
   where $(A_\mu)_{ij} = A_\mu^a T_{ij}^a$.
4. $$
   F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu + g [A_\mu, A_\nu ] \\
   $$
   Explicitly
   $$
   F_{\mu\nu}^a = \partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a + i g f_{bc}{}^a A^b_\mu A_\nu^c
   $$

This completely specifies the Lagrangian of Yang Mills theory. You can now use the variational principle to determine the equations of motion.

Comment: Well ok, but i was expecting explicitely shown euquations of motion :)

Comment: @CheshireCat I doubt anybody will actually show you explicitly how to do this; it is too boring and tedious. But you should take the variation of the field as per usual, both the scalar/fermion field and the gauge fields, to get the E.O.M.

Comment: @CheshireCat - If I gave you the equations of motion, then I would have solved the problem for you.

Comment: That's why i wrote here, i want to see a solution for a problem :) I found something in S. Pokorski, "Gauge field theories", in 1.3 chapter.

Comment: We don't give out solutions on this forum. See the description of the 'homework' tag for details.

Comment: Well whatever, the example is here: http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/rmfe/v56n2/v56n2a3.pdf